# How to make small safari pins?

Tags: safari

I have two different tab groups. The first one has small pins

[image]

The other tab group has large pins

[image]

How do I get the pins to be small like the first tab group?

There isn't an option to make a new "regular window"
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first screenshot is a regular window, it's not actually a tab group.

The second screenshot is a labeled tab group.

Pins behave differently in these two scenarios, as you've observed. There doesn't appear to be a way to change the behavior/appearance of these pins.

Comment: How would I make another "regular window"?

Comment: You get a regular window by going File -> New Window

Comment: ‍♂️ brain fart. Thanks